# histogram giving wrong bins for zero array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
plt.hist(np.zeros((784,1)), bins=2)
```

This should produce histogram with  all values for bin with 0 but the output is:
[image: plot]

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you please clarify what output you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not shure what you are expecting, maybe this helps:

The bins represent intervals. The function computes the occurrences of the input data that fall within each bin (or interval).

Consider this example:

```
plt.hist(np.zeros((784)), bins=(0,1,2))
```

There are 2 intervals, the first for values from `0 to 1` , the second for values from `1 to 2`. So you will have `784` 'counts' in the first and no 'counts' in the second intervall. This will produce the following:

[image]

Now if you replace `bins=(0,1,2)` with `bins=2`, it will use 2 intervals of equal width between the `minimum input` value and the `maximum input` value. Since you have only `zeros` in the input, it takes `-0,5 as minimum` and `+0,5 as maximum`, resulting in the histogram you showed above: no 'counts' between `-0,5 to 0` and all `784 zeros` between `0 and +0,5`.

[image]

So I guess what you want is a thin bar centered at zero, you can get this by e.g. setting bins = some bigger odd number:

```
plt.hist(np.zeros((784)), bins=7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's how `plt.hist` works. For example, you have a list like that `(3, 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 9, 0, 2)` and pass it to `plt.hist` with `bins=3`. Hist distributes all the numbers to 3 categories (e.g. 0-2, 3-6, 7-9) and draws 3 bins. The height of each bin represents the quantity of numbers that were distributed to a corresponding category. In this case, heights will be `(3, 4, 2)`. In your case, `bins=2`, and categories are something like (-0.5-0.0001, 0-0.5). All the 784 zeros are distributed to the second bin, and the fist bin is empty.

There is another function in matplotlob that works as you probably expected `plt.hist` to work. It's `plt.bar`. You can just pass the heights of the bins to it and it will will do nothing to them and just draw a histogram. You can use it like that:

```
plt.bar(np.arange(784), np.zeros((784,1)))
```

and it will give you 784 zero-height bars.